# Large bold(er) text in IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm working on a tag-could style menu on a website: http://web12.leankursus.dk/

It works in chrome, (currently) has some minor problems in firefox and some larger problems in IE (9). The main problems seems to be that IE doesn't make the font *as* bold as Firefox and Chrome. The font need to look like it does in FF or Chrome, but I am unsure what you do when the browser just displays it diffrently

Hope you can help me.

EDIT: Screenshot of the page in IE9 and Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcdWk.jpg

EDIT2: Ah! I've realized I was running IE9 in compatibility mode. Turning that off fixes it in IE9. However - is there any way to make the font work in at least IE8 ?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: of course - I've uploaded a screenshot of the page in IE and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and lower don't support .ttf files for the `@font-face` clause. Use .eot files for IE.

There are some problems with getting it to work in different browsers simultaneously though. Read, for instance, this.
http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/

Comment: But I'm using google webfonts in order to load the fonts. They serve an .eot to IE and should support everything from IE6+